# Problem with mbox command

Tags: math-mode, lists, boxes

I have the following simple code which causes some problems, would be great if someone
could point out what is going wrong here:

```
\begin{compactenum}

\item Perform addition over all bits
  \[
  $\mbox{for~} j \in \{0 \ldots 7\} $ \\
  $r_j = 8 \cdot a_j + 4 \cdot b_j + 2 \cdot x_j + 1 \cdot y_j$
  \]                

 \end{compactenum}
```

LaTeX outputs the following error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.822       $\mbox{for~} j \in
                           \{0 \ldots 7\} $ \
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, i.e. with a minimal preamble required to compile the example.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `\[ ... \]` you cannot use the math mode again. If you want two lines then use `align*` from amsmath or the same without `\[...\]` :

```
  $\mbox{for~} j \in \{0 \ldots 7\} $ \\
  $r_j = 8 \cdot a_j + 4 \cdot b_j + 2 \cdot x_j + 1 \cdot y_j$
```

Comment: also, rather than `\mbox` you might consider using `\text{for~}` if you are using `amsmath`.  this will match the style of the text surrounding the display and also apply the appropriate size if the embedded text occurs in a sub- or superscript.